# Data load fails on initial load but works on subsequent loads

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, vue-component

```
<script>
const Detail = Vue.component('Detail', {

props:  ['id'],

template:`
    <div>
        Pages: {{page}}
        <p><b>ID:</b> {{ id }}</p>

            <h1>{{page.title}}</h1>
            <div  v-if="page.content" v-html="page.content"></div>

    </div>`,

data: function() {
    return {
        page : {}
        };
    },

created () {
    console.log("Initial load with: " + this.id);
    this.fetchData(); // this does not
    },

watch: {
    '$route': 'fetchData' // this works
    },

methods: {

    fetchData () {
        console.log("Getting content for: " + this.id);


        db.collection('pages')
            .where("url", "==", this.id)
            .get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (documentSnapshot) {
                data = documentSnapshot.data(); // I think is is what falls apart
                });
            });
        this.page = data;


        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.page));
        }
    }
}); // end component
```

**Console results**

[image]

**Update**

I added the following code

```
        db.collection('pages')
            .where("url", "==", this.id)
            .get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (documentSnapshot) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(documentSnapshot.data()));
                data = documentSnapshot.data();
                });
            });
        this.page = data;
```

And it show the JSON I am expecting in the console, but it does not change the UI. It still gives the data not defined error.

**Update 2**

```
    fetchData () {
        console.log("Getting content for: " + this.id);

        let data = null;


        db.collection('pages')
            .where("url", "==", this.id)
            .get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (documentSnapshot) {
                data = documentSnapshot.data();

                });
            });
        this.page = data;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.page));
        }
```

Now gets. It failing on initial load and follow up loads too.

[image]

Comment: What is `documentSnapshot` on pageload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a `const` is what was needed needed.

```
    fetchData () {

        console.log("Getting content for: " + this.id);

        db.collection('pages')
            .where("url", "==", this.id)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const {title, content} = doc.data();

                    this.title = title;
                    this.content = content;
                    });
            });

        console.log(this.title);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Your problem is with asynchronous loading. You're making an async call to `db.collection()` but updating your `this.page` in viewModel after making `db.collection()` call. So this is why your `this.page` is not ending up with the data you're desiring to be updated with. Try this & I think it'll work:

```
fetchData () {
    console.log("Getting content for: " + this.id);

    db.collection('pages')
        .where("url", "==", this.id)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                this.page = documentSnapshot.data(); //this.page will hold last documentSnapshot data
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I moved it to mounted, the behavior is the same. I added `let data =  null;` on `fetchData()` and now it doesn't work at at all.

Comment: Can you edit `fetchData()` with `let data = null;` in your question please?

Comment: Thanks! I think I've found the issue @JamesAMohler. Please check!